# How much would Spelltwine add to cards that track how many spells were cast?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast [Spelltwine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpelltwine%5d) and use it to cast two spells from my graveyard and an opponent's, how many spells were cast?

It does say I cast the two spells that I pick, so it should bring me up to three spells total (at least with how I am thinking). Would it count as three spells for [Aetherflux Reservoir](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAetherflux%20Reservoir%5d), [Grapeshot](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrapeshot%5d), and [Sentinel Tower](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSentinel%20Tower%5d)?

Comment: I'm not really sure what information you are asking for that you haven't already provided in the question. Is there some particular reason that you're unsure of what you said?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I am uncertain. I am pretty sure it would work the way I said, but at the same time I do not want to misinform people I play with or build my deck with certain cards and have it for whatever reason not work in the way I think. It is just anxiety pushing me to ask it.

Comment: @murgatroid99 The confusion may be due to some cards having the wording "copy card" while others "copy spell". Twncast, for instance, copies a spell. That doesn't count as casting a spell.

Comment: Magic cards are very literal. Twincast instructs you to copy a spell, so you copy the spell. Spelltwine instructs you to cast a spell, so you cast a spell.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Alrighty, i need to get that understood more. I am used to stuff like D&D where stuff can be up for interpretation.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Keyword Action rules](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Keyword_action), especially the first 20. They define a number of verbs in a way that is specific to Magic.

Comment: Note that for the Ætherflux Reservoir would give you seven lives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Spelltwine instructs you to cast those spells, so you do cast them. This counts for things that check for spells being cast or count how many spells were cast, such as the cards linked in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Spelltwine would add up to three to a storm count. This is because you have spelltwine itself and the two copies of other spells that you have exiled, all of which are being cast.

The reason I say "up to three" is because there are two situations where Spelltwine will not be able to cast targets.

1. The target is no longer in the graveyard when Spelltwine resolves. Say your opponent were to use [Elixir of Immortality](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElixir%20of%20Immortality%5d) while your Spelltwine is on stack, this would put their spell back into their deck, one of the targets to Spelltwine, preventing Spelltwine from exiling, and thus copying this spell. It would still exile and copy the target from your graveyard.
2. The spell being copied is illegal to cast. While timing rules are ignored for Spelltwine, since it forces the cast, other rules are not. You still must be able to legally cast the spell being copied. If you were to target [Hex](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247382) while there are 5 or less creatures in play or [Decimate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDecimate%5d) with no enchantments on the board, Spelltwine would still exile these cards, but you would be unable to cast the copies.

Since you mention Grapeshot, a card with storm, there's another point to make here. If you are casting a card that cares about spells cast before it using Spelltwine, like Grapeshot, you chose the order the exiled cards are to be cast. So you will have the Spelltwine itself counted either way, then can chose to cast the other two in any order. If you put Grapeshot first you get one less copy of Grapeshot. Remember last in, first out, so getting that extra Grapeshot would cause the Grapeshots to resolve first, if that matters for effects (say the other one cared about creatures and grapeshot clears a goblin army, or damage delt this turn)